# Подстановка названия листа из выпадающего списка в FILTER и фильтрация данных в массиве по значению в ячейке

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Использую классическую формулу, чтобы выводить данные из листа

```
=FILTER('Sheet1'!A3:I100;'Sheet1'!E3:E100=A2)
```

Таким образом, я могу отфильтровать нужные данные по предефаинду из ячейки А2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу усовершенствовать эту формулу, чтобы сам лист тоже можно было выбирать из предефаинда в ячейке А1, но у меня ничего не получается. По логике, формула должна быть такой:
`=FILTER(INDIRECT(""&A1&"!A3:I100");INDIRECT(""&A1&"!E3:E100=A2"))`, но в данном случае А2 возвращается в виде текста, на сколько я понимаю. Как исправить эту формулу так, чтобы она отрабатывала подстановку нужной страницы из выпадающего списка А1 и фильтровала необходимые данные из выпадающего списка А2?

Comment: А2 вывести за пределы текста, это же ссылка

Comment: А вот такой костыль родился
=FILTER(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE($A$1;"!A3:A")); REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE($A$1;"!E3:E"));CONCATENATE($A$2;"|^\s*$")))
Этой формулой правильно заполняется один столбец, поэтому приходится дублировать её формулу по всем нужным столбцам и менять параметры на нужные, зато работает.